# Skype installation warning about harm to computer

Tags: files, skype, ubuntu-studio

I wanted to [install Skype](http://www.skype.com/de/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) for my Ubuntu studio. But there was a warning that *this Type of File could harm my Computer*.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if there is not a really good reason, one should only install software from the official Ubuntu repositories.

That said, skype is one of the cases, that this rule has to be broken, because it is not in the official *verse repos. But you are lucky, because Skype is one of the few proprietary applications, that are available in the official Partner repository. To enable it, open software sources and check the partner repo on the third party sources tab. Then reload package information (for instance by running 'sudo apt-get update'  in a terminal), and Skype should be available in software center (or any other package manager frontend like synaptic or aptitude).

Answer (score 0):

such type of warning you will get ususally when ever you are trying to install some software/application from a third party repo's. Skype is not from official Ubuntu repo and its a 3rd party repo from the view of Ubuntu.

What ever the harm thats gonna happen due to 3rd party repo, Ubuntu will not be responsible.

you know the secret is , In the Ubuntu usage from 5 years I have never faced any problem with 3rd party repos.

you are free to go.